# How create many list as array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have a problem on creating a set of list in array

this is my coding but it's wrong one, any correction for this?

```
List<string>[] item = new List<string>[10]();
```

I want to create 10 list in string named as item but I can't do it

and then how can I store more than 1 element in each of the 10 item list??

```
item[1].add(a);     //when I want to print that a I use item[1][0]
item[1].add(b);     //when I want to print that b I use item[1][1]

item[2].add(aa);
item[2].add(bb);
```

but how can I store element in each of the list?

Comment: You're probably looking for `List<string[]> item = new List<new string[10]>();` or something similar

Comment: It's I can ultilize the list like this? item[1] or item[5]................

Comment: No.  You'd have to do `item[1][1];` or similar syntax.  Or just use a simple `List<string>`, unless you really want a List that contains 10 element string arrays, where each element in the `List<T>` is a 10 element string array.

Comment: No, I want 10 list that can contain many element, 10 item with dynamic space

Comment: A `List<T>` can contain any number of elements - it's dynamic.  Are you saying you want 10 separate instances of a `List<T>`, or just one with a dynamic number of elements?

Comment: But how can I add things to a item[1] ?? so also item[2]

Comment: Ya u're right bro, I want 10 separete list that have dynamic space to store things

Comment: is this what you are looking for? `List<string> [] collection = new List<string> [10];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you KNOW for certain that you want exactly ten lists, you can use an array instantiated to 10 items, each a list of string.

```
List<string> [] items = new List<string> [10];
```

Each List is not initialized, so you need to initialize your list before you can use it and each list can be accessed via normal indexer syntax..

```
if (items[0] == null)
    items[0] = new List<string>();
```

Once initialized, you can fill in your data.

```
items[0].Add("another string");
```

If you wanted to pre-initialize each list so that you do not get a NullReferenceException, do so in a loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    items[i] = new List<string>();
```

However, if you think that your items may need to hold more `List<string>` down the road, just simply use a list of lists.

```
List<List<string>> items = new List<List<string>>();
```

List wraps array and gives you some nice syntactic sugar and optimizations for expanding arrays which makes your life a lot easier.  You can still use indexer syntax to access each list within your list.

```
if (items[0] == null)
    items[0] = new List<string>();

items[0].Add("another string").
```

Comment: items[0].Add("another string");
when I use this, it's got error and say that it's null

Comment: @GreenHill It's because you are not initializing that list instance.  In both techniques I initialize the list instance inside of the parent array/list before using.  You cannot miss this crucial step! I also added a quick example of how to initialize each list when using the array parent.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments

> "I want 10 separete list that have dynamic space"

You can define your collection as follows.

```
List<string> [] collection= new List<string> [10];

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
collection[i] = new List<string>();
```

or, if you don't care size of the array then you can use this.

```
List<List<string>> collection = new List<List<string>>();
```

Comment: I like the `List<List<string>>` approach.